# The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I'm integrating Spring and Hibernate. For testing, I'm developing a simple login form. After configuring everything the Error displayed is -

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:The application must supply
>   JDBC connections

I'm attaching code -
hibernate.config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="loginCred.hbm.xml"/> 
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd"> 

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="domain"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

database.properties-

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

and the ERROR -

```
        ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61)
      at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
      at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
      at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
      at dao.loginDa.checkLogin(loginDa.java:23)
      at controller.loginC.auth(loginC.java:29)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my Code for Validation of Login

```
public boolean checkLogin(entityLogin login) 
{
    if(login.equals(null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("inside dao");

        SessionFactory sFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sFactory.openSession();

        Query query=session.createQuery("from entityLogin where username='"+login.getUsername()+"' and password='"+login.getPassword()+"'");
        List ls=query.list();


        if(ls.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("inside list if Empty");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("inside list if All good");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is wrong. You have spring in control of creating a SessionFactory, inject that, don't use a `Configuration` object to obtain one.

Comment: I'm novice in Spring. If you don't mind please elaborate.

Comment: Read about dependency injection in spring (For example @Autowired).